# Android MediaPlayer performs different speed while playing the same video on different devices

Tags: android, media-player

My app needs to play a video on different Android devices at the same time,controlled by a server,all the devices should play the video at same pace.But I got the trouble that while playing on the devices which have better hardware, the video seems fasters than on those with hard ware not that good.I not quite sure with the reason.Can I fix the difference with code and how?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, video playback is clocked by the sound, which plays at constant bitrate (usually, 44kHz). Bideo frames are displayed when the clock says it's their turn to show up. This means that the playback engine must be syncrhonized, to either wait or drop frames if it can't decode them quick enough : this will lead to some jerkiness but avoid a/v desynchronization.

Now, you don't give enough information in your example to help:

- what playback engine are you using ? yours or a standard one? Knowing that there is no such thing as "standard" over a range of android devices spreading over different HW manufacturers or android version...
- what encoding (audio, video), logical transport (mepg2), physical transport (rtsp, adaptive streaming)...

Overall, there is currently no simple answer.

Comment: Thank you.I used the MediaPlayer provided by android framework,but of different sdkversions.